# print nested dictionary using just one for loop or nested for loop

Tags: python, json

I have one python dictionary and i am able to generate desired output using for loop, but i am using multiple for loop rather than 2 different for loops i like to use just one for loop or nested for loop. Here is my code : -

```
nested_dictionary = {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "IT DEPART",
    "team": [

          {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "web",
        "package": [
          {
            "package_name": "packageUIEUIREIRJ",
            "package_url": "Package_url packageUIEUIREIRJ"
          },
          {
            "package_name": "packageZZZZZ",
            "package_url": "Package_url packageZZZZZ"
          },
          {
            "package_name": "packageSADJKSA",
            "package_url": "Package_url packageSADJKSA"
          },
          {
            "package_name": "packageBDF",
            "package_url": "Package_url packageSADJKSA"
          },
          {
            "package_name": "packageXYZ",
            "package_url": "Package_url packageXYZ"
          }
        ]
      },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Mobile",
            "package": [
                {
                    "package_name": "packageUIEUIREIRJ",
                    "package_url": "Mobile packageUIEUIREIRJ"
                },
                {
                    "package_name": "packageZZZZZ",
                    "package_url": "Mobile packageZZZZZ"
                },
                {
                    "package_name": "packageSADJKSA",
                    "package_url": "Mobile packageSADJKSA"
                },
                {
                    "package_name": "packageBDF",
                    "package_url": "Mobile packageSADJKSA"
                },
                {
                    "package_name": "packageXYZ",
                    "package_url": "Mobile packageXYZ"
                }
            ]
        }

    ]
  }
```

```
for p in nested_dictionary['team'][0]['package']:


 name = p['package_name']
 print(name + ' : ' + p['package_url'])

for i in nested_dictionary['team'][1]['package']:
    name_mobile = i['package_name']


    print(name_mobile + ' : ' + p['package_url'])
```

Here is the output i am able to generate currently using multiple 'for' loop but i like to use only one or nested 'for' loop to generate same output.

```
packageUIEUIREIRJ : Package_url packageUIEUIREIRJ
packageZZZZZ : Package_url packageZZZZZ
packageSADJKSA : Package_url packageSADJKSA
packageBDF : Package_url packageSADJKSA
packageXYZ : Package_url packageXYZ
packageUIEUIREIRJ : Package_url packageXYZ
packageZZZZZ : Package_url packageXYZ
packageSADJKSA : Package_url packageXYZ
packageBDF : Package_url packageXYZ
packageXYZ : Package_url packageXYZ
```

Update : I like to make it dynamic so in future if i add more lists it will parse through that too.

Comment: the mobile loop use the web package_url. is it intensional ?

Comment: Yes everything in dictionary is intentional

Comment: Your answer works for now but i like to make it something dynamic

Comment: I have update my answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use :

```
for p in nested_dictionary['team'][0]['package'] + nested_dictionary['team'][1]['package']:
    print(p['package_name'] + ' : ' + p['package_url'])
```

if team can contain a variable number of item :

You can use list comprehension:

```
for p in [item for x in nested_dictionary['team'] for item in x['package']]:
    print(p['package_name'] + ' : ' + p['package_url'])
```

you can also use sum :

```
for p in sum([x['package'] for x in nested_dictionary['team']], []):
    print(p['package_name'] + ' : ' + p['package_url'])
```

or you can do two nested for loop :

```
for x in nested_dictionary['team']:
    for p in x['package']:
        print(p['package_name'] + ' : ' + p['package_url'])
```

Comment: what if a third item is added to the list?

Comment: What if i add 3rd  item in dict.